# symfony2 form querybuilder with parameters

Tags: forms, symfony, builder, query-builder

I want to put my entity in the function of the query builder:

```
->add( 'weeks', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MV\CaravanBundle\Entity\CaravanRow',
    'property' => 'line',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er ) use ( $caravan ) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('w')
                  ->orderBy('w.dateFrom', 'ASC')
                  ->where('w.caravan = ?', $caravan )
                  ->andWhere('w.visible = 1')
                  ->andWhere('w.booked = 0');
}
```

but get the message:

> Expression of type 'Entity\Name' not allowed in this context

So what is the (best) way to give the querybuilder information.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should set the parameter separately like so:

```
->add( 'weeks', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MV\CaravanBundle\Entity\CaravanRow',
    'property' => 'line',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er ) use ( $caravan ) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('w')
                  ->orderBy('w.dateFrom', 'ASC')
                  ->where('w.caravan = ?1')
                  ->andWhere('w.visible = 1')
                  ->andWhere('w.booked = 0')
                  ->setParameter(1, $caravan);
}
```

You can either use an integer or string, but the syntax is slightly different for each. See [the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query)

Comment: your link is died !

Comment: Can i Pass EnityManger Query instead of QueryBuider.? Does it works .?

Answer (score 15):

I recently ran across almost the same problem. Only difference was the 'query_builder' option has to be set inside 'setDefaultOptions'. 
Basicly the form is created like this:

```
$builder->add('field', 'query_type', array('id' => 1));
```

The 'query_type' class looks like this:

```
class QueryType extends AbstractType
{
     public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $options)
     {
              $resolver->setRequired(array('id'));

              $resolver->setNormalizers(array(
                  'query_builder' => function (Options $options, $configs) {
                          return function (EntityRepository $er) use ( $options ) {
                              return $er->getSomething( $options['id'] );

                       };
                  },
              ));
     }
}
```

I use the setNormalizers function to access my $options array and from there on i can call the querybuilder with parameters.

Hope this is useful for someone!

Comment: Good solution if you need options in your anonymous function, when defining default options.