# Symfony2 Form Builder Select Across Join Table with Metadata

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I have 3 entities:

```
[Member] ----OneToMany----> [MemberCategory] ---ManyToOne---> [Category]
```

This works well as far as fetching results from the database, but I can't get the Form Builder to build a correct form controls.

I want a list of all categories with checkboxes that are checked for those categories that are used by the member. Eventually I want to add the priority field.

**Member**

```
class Member
{
    protected $id;

    @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MemberCategory", mappedBy="member")
    protected $categories;
}
```

**Category**

```
class Category
{
    protected $id;

    @ORM\Column(name="category_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false, unique=true)
    private $categoryName;
}
```

**MemberCategory**

```
class MemberCategory
{
    @ORM\Id
    @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Member")
    @ORM\JoinColumns({
    @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
    private $member;

    @ORM\Id
    @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
    @ORM\JoinColumns({
    @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
    private $category;

    @ORM\Column(name="priority", type="integer", nullable=true)
    protected $priority;
}
```

Obvious attempts with the form builder that don't work.

If I use:

```
$builder->add('categories', 'entity', array(
    'class'        => 'SMWMemberBundle:Category',
    'property'     => 'categoryName',
    'multiple'     => true,
    'expanded'     => true,
    'required'     => false
));
```

I get a select with all the categories, but none of those selected in MemberCategory for this member.

If I use:

```
$builder->add('categories', 'entity', array(
    'class'        => 'SMWMemberBundle:MemberCategory',
    'property'     => 'category.categoryName',
    'multiple'     => true,
    'expanded'     => true,
    'required'     => false
));
```

I get all selected categories for all users.

Does anyone know how to get this to work, this is an obvious common pattern in relational data and would be easy using SQL and PHP.

Is there a straight forward solution in Symfony 2.3 and Doctrine?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I resolved this problem in the past (applied to your example) but this is what I figured out so it might not be 100% right for your case.

First create a `MemberCategory` form type matching your needs:

```
<?php    
namespace Company\YourBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MemberCategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('priority')
            ->add('category', 'entity',
                    array('property' => 'name',
                        'class' => 'CompanyYourBundle:Category'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Company\YourBundle\Entity\MemberCategory'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'company_yourbundle_membercategorytype';
    }
}
```

Then add this form type inside your `Member` type form:

```
<?php

namespace Company\YourBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MemberType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('members', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new MemberCategoryType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,));
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Company\YourBundle\Entity\Member'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'company_yourbundle_membertype';
    }
}
```

Then you can follow [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) to add as many categories as you want to your members and assigning a priority every time.

Comment: The documentation makes it appear that adding and removing categories would be a huge amount of trouble, even involving client side code. Is that the case or am I misreading the docs?

Comment: You read it right! That's the way I did it, not sure it is the best way tho. I'll look at the other answers as well because I agree with you about this being a common pattern without any clear documentation on the official website.

Comment: Thanks, the Doctrine docs describe how to deal with this from the entity side in http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html (see use case 3). But they provide nothing on using this with a Symfony form.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the querybuilder inside your form

```
$builder->add('categories', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'SMWMemberBundle:MemberCategory',
        'property'     => 'category.categoryName',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er ) use ( ? ) {
           return $er->createQueryBuilder( ? )

          // your query with a left join probably

         }
        'multiple'     => true,
        'expanded'     => true,
        'required' => false
    ));
```

See documentation for proper use.
see [symfony2 form querybuilder with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846970/symfony2-form-querybuilder-with-parameters) for an exmple

Comment: Please complete your answer, as the main part is commented out in your answer

Answer (score 0):

The post of cheesemacfly is not so bad, but it is call embeded form and can be complicated to manage.
In fact, you jus need to create a "Custom Repositories"
 http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

It will add a new methods for "grabbing" your ORM object with Doctrine2 like find() or findBy();

1)  Create a new repository in a Repository Folder of your Bundle

```
<?php
  namespace YourVendor\SMWMemberBundle\Repository;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

  class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository{

  public function UsedByMember($member){
  return $this
         ->createQueryBuilder('c')
         ->leftJoin('c.Member', 'mc')
         ->where('mc.member = ?1')
         ->setParameter(1, $member);
}
```

}

2) Attached your Cutom repository to your Entity

```
namespace YourVendor\SMWMemberBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourVendor\SMWMemberBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="Category") 
*/
class Category{
```

3) add a constructor to your Form class and pass de Entity Manager and the variable required to your query :

```
class CategoryUserForm extends AbstractType
{
   private $em;
   private $member ;


   public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $site, $seed)
   {
       $this->em = $em;
       $this->member = $member;

   }

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $qb = $this->em->getRepository('SMWMemberBundle:Category')->UsedByUsers($this->member);
    $builder->add('categories', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'SMWMemberBundle:MemberCategory',
        'query_builder'     => $qb,
        'multiple'     => true,
        'expanded'     => true,
        'required' => false
    ));
 }
```

4) In your controller, you create your form like that :

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new CategoryUserForm($em, $member), $category);
```

Feel free to ask me questions, I'm hope this is what you are looking for ;)