# Query Builder inside Symfony2 Entity Form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, doctrine-query

Right now I have a problem with the query builder function of the entity form type inside Symfony.

Other questions on this board did not help me to find a solution:
See e.g.: [8456298](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456298/custom-query-in-entity-field-type) or [13846970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846970/symfony2-form-querybuilder-with-parameters) or [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676773/symfony-form-query-buider-and-entity-repository)

Here's the situation: I want to add a email address to send a rating on request. Ratings are children of a Doctor class, which is a child of User (FOS User Bundle is used here)

So here's my code:

The controller:

```
public function AddPatientAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(new AddPremiumRatingType(), '', array('user'=> $user));
    return $this->render('Acme/DemoBundle:Dashboard/Premium:addpatient.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form
                ));
}
```

Here is the AddPremiumRatingType Class:

```
class AddPremiumRatingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('doctor', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Arztprofil',
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'JBauleRatingBundle:Doctor',
                'mapped' => false,
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function(DoctorRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    $user = $options['user'];
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                                ->select('d')
                                ->where('d.user = ?1')
                                ->setParameter('1', $user->getId());
             }))
            ->add('emails', 'collection', array(
                'label' => 'E-Mail Adressen',
                'type'   => 'email',
                'mapped' => false,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'prototype_name' => '__name__',
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'E-Mail Adresse',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                    'required' => false
                )
            )) 
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label'     => 'Patienten hinzufügen'
            ));                  
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'rating';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\PremiumRating',
        ));
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'user',
        ));
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes(array(
            'user' => 'Acme\LoginChildBundle\Entity\User',
        ));
    }

}
```

And finally here's the Error I get:

`Expected argument of type "object, array or empty", "string" given`

Also I tried:

- Outsource the QueryBuild in a Repository Class and call the repository class => got the same Error
- Only use the Create Query Command => Error that the query must be an instance of the QueryBuilder
- Reading the Docs of Doctrine and Symfony ...couldn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're unable to render your form at all, since you're receiving that error on creation.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AddPremiumRatingType(), '', array('user'=> $user));
```

The second argument that `createForm()` receives is flagged as `mixed`. And as the error says, it have to be either an `object` or `array()` or simply `null`.

Change your line to:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AddPremiumRatingType(), array(), array('user'=> $user));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)